# Postgres Multiple Column Text Indexing and filtering

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I could not find any conclusive answers reading some of the existing posts on this topic, for my use case.
I have a website that will query data from postgres database, using a search bar and some filters.

Queries will look like this

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_ LIKE '%TEXT%' 
 OR ref_id_ LIKE '%TEXT%' 
 OR name_ LIKE '%TEXT%'
 OR fileName_ LIKE '%TEXT%'
 ORDER BY id_/startDate_/endDate_ ASC/DESC LIMIT X OFFSET Y
```

The column on which we sort may vary. Is there a way to create an efficient index for this?

Comment: What did you already try?  What is the current execution like? Show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) please.  How fast does it need to be?  How many rows are in the table? What is X?  What is Y?  Is the TEXT really TEXT?  How many rows would satisfy the query if not for the LIMIT and OFFSET?

Comment: I tried to create indexes on my table like this `  CREATE INDEX idx_gist ON import USING gist (name_  gist_trgm_ops);`` for each columns. But it seems to take a bit longer when indexes are present;
The text to search is not "TEXT", it will be the text typed by the user of the website into the search bar, it is variable.
The number of rows will depend on the text, but generally it shouldn't exceed 100 rows (The table has ~3M rows );

X is the limit of rows we want to display on the HTML page ( it's 10), Y is the page number